# How to restrict users to their subdomain

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a web application where I intend to give each client their own subdomain, like client1.myapp.com, client2.myapp.com, etc. When a user logs in, I store their user ID in the session variable, like `$_SESSION['user'] = 4;` When `$_SESSION['user']` is set, the user is logged in and can access the application. Since user IDs are only unique within each individual client, I need a way to keep users from accessing other clients' subdomains. I considered using the session cookie for that, but then I figured cookies can be hacked. Now I'm thinking of assigning each client a unique client ID and using `$_SESSION[$clientID]['user']` instead of `$_SESSION['user']`. Is that a safe way of solving the problem? What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your `$clientID` approach.

If you want to get fancy, you could do something like use [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) so the same `PHPSESSID` cookie could be accessible to all domains and subdomains. This has its benefits especially if your centralized log-in page needs to detect if the user is logged-in for a particular domain or subdomain. Or if you wish to allow a user to log out from all subdomains at the same time, or if you'd like to create an administrative account which can access all subdomains.

Never trust the session id being sent, even if the cookie is tied to a specific subdomain, since the sessions for all subdomains are being [stored](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) in the same directory on the server.
A solution for this might be:  `ini_set(session.save_path, "/path/to/your/folder/$clientid")` then you'd have a unique directory dedicated for each client for storing sessions. The benefit of this approach is that your `$_SESSION` won't contain information related to another subdomain.

You can also take advantage of [sesssion_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) so instead of `PHPSESSID` you could use client1 or client2 to it's clear which client the session belongs to.
e.g. `client2=8d72edf35377a27388cb;client8=b47277bc8e3d4a5f`
then PHP can read this cookie and know the client the session exists for.

You can also use a combination of all of the above, whatever works for you.
See the session-related functions here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php
And the session-related settings here: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. I hope this will help.

When a user logs in, store their subdomain in the session variable like:

```
$_SESSION['user_subdomain'] = 'client1.myapp.com';
```

And when `$_SESSION['user']` and `$_SESSION['user_subdomain']` is set, the user is logged in and accessing the application then just check the current accessing application's subdomain is equal to `$_SESSION['user_subdomain']` or not.

By using this way you can redirect a client on its correct application's subdomain, if he tried to access other clients' subdomains. In this way you can keep users from accessing other clients' subdomains.